# How to move data to solr production instance without re-indexing?

Tags: solr

We have an offline system where we consume input documents from external sources, transform them and store them in solr, one collection at a time.

There is a production solr instance with a different configuration than the offline solr instance (but with the same version of solr) that the data needs to be moved to once it is ready. This is set to run periodically and everytime there is new incoming data, it will replace the documents of a collection with the same name and schema in the production instance.

Is it in any way possible to do this without having to re-index the collection in the production instance? Is there some sort of back-up and restore mechanism that will allow us to copy the data, index and all, into the production system with minimal downtime?

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: @cheffe I'm using solr 5.3.0

Comment: Can you use standard replication? (and replicate on commit/optimize)

Comment: @MatsLindh The offline solr instance is not large enough to house all the data at any given point of time in order for it to be the master instance. It is really a "scratch" database that the offline processes write to instead of directly writing to the production server.

Comment: @MatsLindh But yes, I can see how standard replication is doable. Will it be a problem if the two solr cores are in two different data centers?

Answer (score 17):

You can try making backup on one system, and a restore on the other system:

Backup:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=backup&location=d:\\solr-backup
```

Restore:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=restore&location=d:\\solr-backup
```

Change `localhost:8983` to your server's name and port (backup on one, restore on the other),  `your-collection-name` to your core-name, `d:\\solr-backup` is the folder on the server, where the backups will be located in (make sure, you copy the backup-data from one server to the other).

See also the [solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups).

Comment: can we backup solr index from one cluster and restore that index on another cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try this:-

Backup:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=BackupName&collection=CollectionName&location=/BackupLocation
```

Restore:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=BackupName&location=/BackupLocation&collection=CollectionName
```

Note: No need to create collection restore URL will take care.

Comment: How can i use this when I am using the standalone mode, using this gives me an error stating `Solr instance is not running in SolrCloud mode`